# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064- joins whit different tables

Tags: php, laravel, multiple-join-rows

I´m trying to code this with laravel:

```
$software = $row['DisplayName0'];
$equipo = $row['Netbios_Name0'];
//echo $software ."</br>";
$sqlconsulta2= "select DISTINCT NOMSOF, TIPLICSOF, TIPIMASOF, IDEMP, NOMEMP, APPEMP, APMEMP from equ,emp 
LEFT JOIN sof
ON sof.NOMSOF = '$software'
where IDEEQU = '$equipo'  and IDEEMP = IDEMP and pueemp = 'Empleado'";
```

I try a lot of forms to do that but I don´t know how to do it. I have this at the moment but it appears an error of syntax

```
 $lichome = DB::connection('mysql')->table('emp')->select('SOF.NOMSOF', 'SOF.TIPLICSOF', 'SOF.TIPIMASOF', 'EMP.IDEMP',
        'EMP.NOMEMP','EMP.APPEMP', 'EMP.APMEMP')
        ->where('pueemp', '=', 'Empleado')
        ->join('equ','EQU.IDEMP', '=', 'EMP.IDEEMP')
        ->whereIn('EQU.IDEEQU', $home->pluck('Netbios_Name0'))
        ->join('sof','NOMSOF', '=', $home->pluck('DisplayName0'))
        ->where('pueemp', '=', 'Empleado')->get();
```

Can anybody help me? 
Thank you.

Comment: what $home variable contains? 

$home->pluck will return array so the problem is that.

Comment: $home = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->table('v_R_System_valid')->select ('v_R_System_valid.Netbios_Name0', 'v_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName0',
             'v_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.Version0', 'v_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.InstallDate0')
             ->join('v_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS', 'v_R_System_valid.ResourceID', '=','v_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.ResourceID')
             ->where('v_R_System_valid.Netbios_Name0', '=', 'DMXL3211')->where('v_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName0', '<>', '')
             ->orderBy('v_R_System_valid.Netbios_Name0', 'ASC')->distinct();

Answer (score 0):

$home->pluck() method will return Illuminate\Support\Collection

Instead you must use $home->get($key)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `joins` first, and then use the `where` clauses and also, using `get()`.

```
 $lichome = DB::connection('mysql')
        ->table('emp')->select('SOF.NOMSOF',
                               'SOF.TIPLICSOF',
                               'SOF.TIPIMASOF',
                               'EMP.IDEMP',
                               'EMP.NOMEMP',
                               'EMP.APPEMP',
                               'EMP.APMEMP')
        ->join('equ','EQU.IDEMP', '=', 'EMP.IDEEMP')
        ->join('sof','NOMSOF', '=', $home->get('DisplayName0'))
        ->whereIn('EQU.IDEEQU', $home->pluck('Netbios_Name0'))
        ->where('pueemp', '=', 'Empleado')
        ->where('pueemp', '=', 'Empleado')->get();
```

You should know:

> `pluck()` Retrieves all of the values for a given key
>
> `get()` Returns the item at a given key. If the key does not exist,
>   null is returned.

So, you can use `pluck` within `whereIn()` **but you can not use it on a `on` clause within join**, it's better to use `get()`.

So, here:

```
->join('sof','NOMSOF', '=', $home->pluck('DisplayName0'))
```

You are doing something like:

```
...
INNER JOIN sof ON nomsof = ['item1', 'item2']
```

Also, I think you should do it like this:

```
->join('sof','sof.NOMSOF', '=', 'equ.SomeID')
```